# how to save audio files in specific folder in sd card(at present files are saving directly in sdcard)

Tags: android, save, android-sdcard

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Date;
import cafe.adriel.androidaudiorecorder.AndroidAudioRecorder;
import cafe.adriel.androidaudiorecorder.Util;
import cafe.adriel.androidaudiorecorder.example.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    public static final String EXTRA_FILE_PATH = "filePath";

    public static final String EXTRA_COLOR = "color";
    static Date createdTime= new Date();
    public static final String AUDIO_FILE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + createdTime + "_rec.wav";
    public static final int RECORD_AUDIO = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)));
        }

        Util.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        Util.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RECORD_AUDIO) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Audio recorded successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Audio was not recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void recordAudio(View v) {
        AndroidAudioRecorder.with(this)
                .setFilePath(AUDIO_FILE_PATH)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.recorder_bg))
                .setRequestCode(RECORD_AUDIO)
                .record();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is in external memory. Not on SD card. But just as you added a file name to that parh you can add a folder name first.

Comment: this will fail if the added folder name does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using one [Android's default external storage folders](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)), in your case the [DIRECTORY_MUSIC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_MUSIC) like this

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
```

You can use this [File class constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to create a new folder on the SD card:

```
File audioFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
    "newaudiofolder")
if (!audioFolder.exists()) {
    boolean success = audioFolder.mkdir()
    if (success) {
        // save the file 
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not a folder on an SD card but a folder in external memory. Look at the function name.

Comment: Not all devices have an sd card slot. According to [Google Documenation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal), external storage  `can be a removable storage media (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage` - so to me and to the original poster, the external storage seems to be the right choice.

Comment: Well if there is no SD card slot then there is certainly no SD card. Only external memory. The OP spoke about SD card.

Comment: thanks man,folder is created,but now how to proceed with saving my recorded audio file into that folder